# Keyword to label mapping for list column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column named `surface-wordings` in my df named `difference`, which has values like this:

```
['paths-modified-/clusters/{cluster_id}/hosts/{host_id}/instructions-operations-modified-POST-parameters-modified-body-reply-schema-properties-modified-step_type-enum-deleted']
```

I have a keyword to label mappings defined, and from this column I want to extract the keywords and assign the label under a new column named `labels`. The mapping is as follows:

```
keyword_label_mappings = {
    'POST-parameters-modified': 'POST Parameters Modified',
    'PUT-parameters-modified': 'PUT Parameters Modified',
}
```

I am not sure how could I achieve this, any suggestions or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Can you provide the output of `print(difference['surface_wordings'].head(5))` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly modified your `keyword_label_mappings` dict to have an output with your second sample:

```
keyword_label_mappings = {
    'POST-parameters-modified': 'POST Parameters Modified',
    'PUT-parameters-modified': 'PUT Parameters Modified',
    'POST-responses-modified': 'POST Responses Modified',
    'DELETE-summary-from': 'DELETE Summary Changed',
    'POST-responses-deleted': 'POST Responses Deleted',
    'POST-parameters-added': 'POST Parameters Added',
    'POST-parameters-deleted': 'POST Parameters Deleted',
    'GET-summary-to': 'GET Summary To',  # added for demo
    'GET-summary-from': 'GET Summary From',  # added for demo
}
```

Use `str.extract` to extract keys of your dict then `map` to replace with values:

```
pattern = fr"({'|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in keyword_label_mappings)})"

difference['labels'] = (
    difference['surface_wordings'].explode().str.extractall(pattern)[0]
                                  .map(keyword_label_mappings).droplevel('match')
                                  .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> difference
                                                                      surface_wordings                              labels
63657  [paths-modified-/pets-operations-modified-GET-summary-from, paths-modified-/...  [GET Summary From, GET Summary To]
63658  [info-version-from, info-version-to, paths-modified-/pets-operations-modifie...  [GET Summary From, GET Summary To]
63659  [paths-modified-/pets-operations-modified-GET-summary-from, paths-modified-/...  [GET Summary From, GET Summary To]
63661  [info-title-from, info-title-to, info-license-deleted, info-version-from, in...  [GET Summary From, GET Summary To]
63662  [openAPI-from, openAPI-to, paths-added, paths-deleted, endpoints-added, endp...                                 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets go over your algorithm, for example we have one row and the value of the column `surface-wordings` is:

```
[paths-modified-/clusters/{cluster_id}/hosts/{host_id}/instructions-operations-modified-POST-parameters-modified-body-reply-schema-properties-modified-step_type-enum-deleted]
```

after this line `for keyword_list in difference['surface_wordings']:` we will have mentioned value inside `keyword_list`

After that the line `for keyword in keyword_list.split(', '):` will return the same string because there is no ", " inside the mentioned row, so keyword is the same as keyword list.

This line `keyword = keyword.split('-')[0]` will return the word `[paths` because the entire thing you wrote was string I suppose. So this new word is definitely not matching your keys in the `keyword_label_mappings` dictionary and it will return `[]` at the end.

First of all try debugging your code, if you are using debugging tools better and if not use `print` statements to see the values of splits and etc. Also you have to check all the values and should try to find some pattern between data in order to find better algorithm of splitting and getting the key you want for checking inside the dictionary.

Also it would be better to provide `difference.head()` to get better idea of your `df` if this one still does not work.